# jquery show specific element then hide when another is selected

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using slider and having it open up on a specific image when the page loads. That happens just fine, only when I go to select another image it stays visible as the other one also pops up. 
Here is my current code for forcing it to appear.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#793").show();  
});
</script>
```

the page can be seen here, select another image at the bottom and you'll see what I mean.
http://www.shehitpausestudios.com/index.php/shop/polaroids/girls-and-dreams/last-summer/

Comment: That's not your jQuery, that's your php script. What does that look like when it's seen by the browser ('view source')? Also, what's your relevant html? Can we see a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Sorry, re-posted the code as seen in the browser. I provided the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try something like this

```
$(".bjqs li div").click(function(){
        $(".person_about").hide();
        var image = $(this).attr("data-rel");
        var div = image.replace('#','');
        $(".person_about #"+div).show(); 
       return false;
    });
```

Comment: You are amazing sir. That did the trick spot on. It took me a minute to decipher it, but it did it, and it did it beautifully. Thank you so much.

If you couldn't tell, I'm definitely a beginner in jquery. I'm mostly on html, css, and php.

Comment: not a problem, happy to help. we all gotta start somewhere, the best way to learn is to read the code and get to understand it. (if this was the answer you were looking for, please mark as accepted answer) :)